# What permission/user does apache2 use to write django logs

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have very good question which I would like an expert to comment on that for me please. (perhaps Graham Dumpleton)

So I have a Django web application (developed on ubuntu 16.04) which loges some failures as below on /var/log/apache2/APPNAME.log.

since all files in /var/log/apache2 have root:adm owner, I granted ownership of my log file the same way and I made sure www-data is a member of adm group. Then I granted rwx to adm group for owner group and I tested everything was working fine.

After 24hr the permission of the file and the parent folder has changed and I can see the write permission has been revoked from the log file and the parent directory causing permission denied error in error because the log file couldn't be written.

Here are my questions if you could kindly help:

1) where is the right place to put Django log files?

2) What process under what user permission writes the file?

3) Which process resets permissions in the /var/log/apache and why?

Thank you much in advance,

I hope this question help others too.

Cheers,
Mike

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django import forms
from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMessage
from StudioHanel.forms import ContactForm

import traceback
import time

# import the logging library
import logging
import sys

# Get an instance of a logger
#logger = logging.getLogger('APPNAME')

def contact(request):
    logger.debug('Contact Start!') 

    if request.method == 'POST':
        etc...
```

## settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },

    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },

        'applogfile': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join('/var/log/apache2', 'APPNAME.log'),
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*15,  15MB
            'backupCount': 10,
        },


     },

    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'APPNAME': {
            'handlers': ['applogfile',],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is the operating system. Web server is apache 2.4.18. Djagno 1.7. And please rate the question if you think it can help others too. cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1) where is the right place to put Django log files?**

Recently I initiated a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/django-users/directories%7Csort:relevance/django-users/WATVnkg6wdg/kON_p_gAAwAJ) in the django-users mailing list about the directories to use for Django projects, and I concluded there is no standard practice. I've settled on using `/var/log/django-project-name`.

In any case, `/var/log/apache2` is the wrong place because of the problem you identified, that `logrotate` will interfere. More on that below.

**2) What process under what user permission writes the file?**

If you use Gunicorn, it's the `gunicorn` process, and if you use uWSGI, it's `uwsgi`. Judging from your reference to Graham Dumpleton, you are using mod_wsgi. So the process is the mod_wsgi daemon.

The user as which these processes are writing to the file is the user as which the process runs. For mod_wsgi, you can specify a `user` option to the `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive. According to [its documentation](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html), "If this option is not supplied the daemon processes will be run as the same user that Apache would run child processes and as defined by the User directive." In Ubuntu, this is `www-data`. I think it's a good idea to use the `user` option and run the daemon as a different dedicated user.

You should not add `www-data` to the `adm` group. The `adm` group is people who have permission to read the log files. `www-data` should not have such permission. (Reading and writing its own log files is fine, but you wouldn't want it to have permission to read `/var/log/syslog`.)

**3) Which process resets permissions in the /var/log/apache and why?**

It's `logrotate`, which is run by cron; see `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`. The configuration at `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2` manipulates all files matching `/var/log/apache2/*.log`. The primary purpose of `logrotate` is to, well, rotate logs. That is, it creates a new log file every day, yesterday's is named `access.log.1`, before yesterday's `access.log.2.gz`, and so on, and logs older than some days are deleted. This is done to save space and to keep the logs manageable. `logrotate` will also fix the permissions of the files if they are wrong.

In theory you should configure `logrotate` to also rotate your Django project's logs, otherwise they might eventually fill the disk.

Answer (score 1):

For mod_wsgi you are better to direct Python logging to `stderr` or `stdout` so that it is captured in the Apache error log. Don't create a separate log file as by using Apache log file, things like log file rotation will be handled for you automatically. For an example see under 'Logging of Python exceptions' in:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/integrating-modwsgi-express-as-django.html

Do ensure though that you configure a separate error log for Apache for the `VirtualHost` so that your logging for site is saved away separately to main Apache error log.